# UIActivityViewController drops items from the activityItems

Tags: swift, uikit, uiactivityviewcontroller

In Swift, sharing content seems pretty easy. One defines a button with an action to call the UIActivity View Controller. When one just wants to share a picture in the Asset catalogue together with a line of text these lines of code work and populate the text and image for 'some' Apps. For some apps they drop either the image or the text.

1. Facebook Messenger : Text Dropped
2. WhatsApp : Image Dropped
3. Signal :Text Dropped
4. Mail : both ok!
5. Stocktwits: both ok!
6. Discord: both ok!
7. LinkedIn: Image Dropped
8. iMessage: both ok!

[Code]

```
    var text: String = "Check out this App!"
    let image: UIImage = UIImage(named: "SharePic")!

    let shareItems : [Any] = [(image), text]
    let av = UIActivityViewController(activityItems: shareItems, applicationActivities: nil)
    UIApplication.shared.windows.first?.rootViewController!.present(av, animated: true, completion: nil)
```

Is this a bug in UIKit? It doesn't make sense that Facebook Messenger would drop the text.

Does one need to revert to regular Swift to get this to work?

Comment: I don't think this has anything to do with SwiftUI. UIActivityViewController is a part of UIKit. If both items work in not only the default Apple apps, but also a handful of 3rd party apps, I'm having trouble figuring out why this wouldn't be a bug with the apps and not the Apple framework/API.

Comment: take Facebook messenger for instance. if you share just a text it works. if you share just a pic it works. but if you try and share both it drops the text.  this is maybe a 3rd party decision to allow you to only share one thing at a time? seems silly to me.

Comment: I agree, but if it works in Stocktwits and Discord, as well as the default Apple apps, unless there's evidence otherwise (which maybe someone else will chime in with), seems like the framework/API works fine.

Comment: yes maybe its not a Swift problem. Funnily now sharing to Twitter app has dropped as an option as well. Even though I have Twitter open. This seems all too mysterious to me. Wants me to go bug hunting for the day! phew.